# How do I removeItem() from localStorage?

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage, shopping-cart

[image]
[image]

Hi, I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to code a shopping cart.

I have 3 products in cart under the key **"productsInCart"**. I only want the product of the row where the removed button was clicked to be removed but then when I press on the remove button, all of the 3 items in cart get removed. Is there any solution to this? I'm guessing that the
`localStorage.removeItem("productsInCart")` should be changed to remove the specific item but I'm not sure how to go about.

I added the `item.inCart = 0;` so that I can update the localStorage to display the correct total number of items in cart(`cartNumbers`) and the `totalCost`. Again this changes all of the 3 products to be 0 "inCart", not the specific one the user wants.

Comment: could you add your code as text into the question please

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem with code, people who are volunteering to help need the text of the code. Images of the code are not an acceptable substitute.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: [Please don't artificially add tags to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 2):

From what I got from your question:

You need to have a collection of items, perhaps an JS array like:

```
const items = [{}, {}, {}];
```

The length of this array will also give you the number of items, so that you do not have to maintain it explicitly.

You need to set this array in localStorage as:

```
localStorage.setItem('itemList', JSON.stringify(items));
```

When you click remove, you need to remove the item from list. Read about methods to remove element from array (`pop`, `splice`, `slice` etc)

```
items.splice(index, 1);
```

Thereafter you need to set the updated item again in the local storage.

Read more here : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the item you want in your JavaScript code from the array, (e.g. using [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) command) and then UPDATE the `removeItem` array in your localStorage, not remove it.

So since you can store data only in text format in localStorage, you need to parse it back and forth when you do any update (so `JSON.stringify` & `JSON.parse`)

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly modify localStorage data. You should replace data.
What you can do is when you remove an item get the item index in array and then read localStorage data, remove the item from array, after that again save data to localStorage.

```js
var existingItems = JSON.JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'))
var itemIndex = 1 // index of item to be removed

existingItems.splice(itemIndex, 1)

localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(existingItems));
```